# Rectangularize a list-of-lists structure

Tags: python, array

Considering I have an iterated "lists of lists ..." (up to 4 dimensions), now I wish to make the full list "rectangular" (or well each dimension equal in size). For a 4 dimensional case I've written out a specific version:

```
x=[[[[4,3,4,5],[1],[2,2]],[[3,6,7],[2,3],[1]]],[[[1]]]]

length0 = len(x)
length1 = len(sorted(x,key=len, reverse=True)[0])
length2 = 0
length3 = 0
for xi in x:
    lengthi = len(sorted(xi,key=len, reverse=True)[0])
    for xii in xi:
        lengthii = len(sorted(xii,key=len, reverse=True)[0])
        length3 = max(lengthii, length3)
    length2 = max(lengthi, length2)
tlist3 = [None]
tlist2 = [tlist3 * length3]
tlist1 = [tlist2 * length2]

for xi in x:
    for xii in xi:
        for xiii in xii:
            xiii.extend(tlist3*(length3 - len(xiii) ))
        xii.extend(tlist2*(length2 - len(xii)))
    xi.extend(tlist1 * (length1 - len(xi)))

print(x)
```

It works, but that's everything I can say about this code (it doesn't look clean, nor is it scalable to more dimensions easily).

Ideally I would've a function that goes up to N dimensions into a given list, and rectangulars everything

As a side note: this is for insertion into a NumPy array.

Comment: By "rectangular", you mean "cubic", i.e. the same length in each dimension? (Or, more precisely, an N-dimensional hypercube, where N=4 in your example?)

Comment: @200_success - no it needs to me "N[0] x N[1] ... N[n]"  - each dimension has it's own length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can find a maximum without sorting. Instead of

  ```
  len(sorted(x,key=len, reverse=True)[0])
  ```

  you can use either of these:

  ```
  len(max(x, key=len))
  max(len(s) for s in x)
  ```

For a more generic solution I propose this:

```
import itertools

def rectangularize(nested_list, dimensions, fill_value=None):
    flat = nested_list
    for dim in range(dimensions-2, -1, -1):
        size = max(len(s) for s in flat)
        for s in flat:
            s.extend([] if dim else fill_value for _ in range(size - len(s)))
        flat = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(flat))

x=[[[[4,3,4,5],[1],[2,2]],[[3,6,7],[2,3],[1]]],[[[1]]]]
rectangularize(x, 4)
print(x)
```

To explain:

- The `flat` list is a flattened view of one dimension of `nested_list`. It contains references to sublists of `nested_list`; extending the sublists through `flat` mutates `nested_list`.
- `flat = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(flat))` advances `flat` to the next dimension by concatenating the sublists.
- The main loop runs `dimensions-1` times because the outermost list never needs to be extended.
- I'm using `range(dimensions-2, -1, -1)` to make `dim == 0` in the final iteration where a different fill value is needed, so I can use a clean `if dim else` to deal with that.

Comment: Could you provide more of an explanation of your solution?

Comment: @200_success indeed I find it working and looking very clean.. But it is not easy to understand and how it actually iterates escapes me.

Comment: @paul23 [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) is magic. Very powerful mathemagic. Basically it creates a for in a for in a for, for as many dimensions as you need.